# Javascript Uncaught TypeError: checkbox.setAttributeNode is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, json, getelementsbyname

I got an error and i don't know how to resolve it, pls help :)
The code:

```
var ls_contextid1=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('completedArray')) || [];
      for (var i = 0; i < ls_contextid1.length; i++){
        var obj = ls_contextid1[i];
        for (var key in obj){
          var value = obj[key];
          var checkbox=document.getElementsByName(value);
          doc[i] =value;

          var att = document.createAttribute('checked');      
          att.value = 'checked';   

        checkbox.setAttributeNode(att);

        }
      }
```

}

this is the error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: checkbox.setAttributeNode is not a function
```

Local storage contains the json:

```
[{"contextid":"470"},{"contextid":"468"},{"contextid":"467"},{"contextid":"463"},{"contextid":"463"},{"contextid":"464"}]
```

And the HTML code:

```
<input name="470" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" style="margin-left:50px;">
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByName` returns collection, so you need use `checkbox[0].setAttributeNode(att);`. I also recommend you check element's existing before setting attribute.

Answer (score 3):

The [getElementsByName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns a nodelist collection with a given name in the  document. So you should access first element, by doing

```
checkbox[0].setAttributeNode(att);
```

Answer (score 3):

`document.getElementsByName(value);` returns a node *list* instead of just a single node. You should loop over the list and use `setAttributeNode()` on each of the nodes in the list.